# NSURLCache ignores `max-age` on 304 (Not Modified) responses

Tags: ios, macos

When receiving responses with status code `200`, NSURLCache does get updated correctly and considers `max-age` in the `Cache-Policy`.
If the cache has expired it also correctly sends conditional requests using `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match`, if the corresponding headers were retrieved previously.
If now the server responds with status code `304` (`Not Modified`), it does not update the cache with the new response.
This means it still considers the cached response to be expired and continues to make conditional requests to the server.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report with Apple for this issue?

Comment: In my testing it looks like this has been fixed in iOS 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked around the issue by manually updating the cache when necessary.
The problem is that NSURLCache works transparently, so in a NSURLConnectionDelegate you cannot directly verify if the response came from the cache.
So I infer that the response needs to be updated by comparing the `Data` header to the cached response:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (_response.statusCode == 200) {
        NSString *date = _response.allHeaderFields[@"Date"];
        NSCachedURLResponse *cached = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:_connection.originalRequest];
        if (cached) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *cachedResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)cached.response;
            NSString *cachedDate = cachedResponse.allHeaderFields[@"Date"];
            if (![date isEqualToString:cachedDate]) {
                NSCachedURLResponse *updatedCache = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:_response data:_data];
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] storeCachedResponse:updatedCache forRequest:_connection.originalRequest];
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```